# ambiguous calls in nanopolish

Tags: nanopore, methylation

I am converting scores into frequencies (from nanopolish results) using [Nanopore scripts](https://nanopolish.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart_call_methylation.html).
The script filters out lots of rows on the premise that reads where `LLR < T * N` are ambiguous.

where:

```
LLR = log-likelihood ratio (log-likelihood methylated / log-likelihood unmethylated)  
T   = arbitrary threshold. Above that value the C is methylated.  
N   = number of Cs (CpG) in the fragment analyzed.
```

What? Why? Where?

Comment: What's the question here? If there is not enough support for a position, it gets filtered out...

Comment: I'm assuming that you are using the workflow defined here: https://nanopolish.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart_call_methylation.html . Can you give more information about where you are in the process of the "Nanopore scripts?" I am guessing that you are at `calculate_methylation_frequency.py` based on available information, and in that case it is as simple as Wouter de Coster says.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that it is the postprocessing script `calculate_methylation_frequency.py` that you are using, user Wouter de Coster's comment is correct that the methylation event is filtered out at the frequency estimation stage if it has a low LLR. It will have  a low LLR if it is considered not confident enough to report. This means not only `LLR > T * N`, but also the statistical threshold `LLR > 0` (see below).

Specifically, here is the code in the [script](https://github.com/jts/nanopolish/blob/master/scripts/calculate_methylation_frequency.py):

```
def update_call_stats(key, num_called_cpg_sites, is_methylated, sequence):
    if key not in sites:
        sites[key] = SiteStats(num_called_cpg_sites, sequence)

    sites[key].num_reads += 1
    sites[key].called_sites += num_called_cpg_sites
    if is_methylated > 0:
        sites[key].called_sites_methylated += num_called_cpg_sites
```

That is the function that decides whether to add a site to output, which depends on `is_methylated`, which is set here:

```
    # [skip several lines of code]
        num_sites = int(record['num_motifs'])
        llr = float(record['log_lik_ratio'])

        # Skip ambiguous call
        if abs(llr) < args.call_threshold * num_sites:
            # [MP NOTE: SKIP if LLR < T * N]
            continue
        sequence = record['sequence']

        # [MP NOTE: SKIP IF LLR <= 0]
        is_methylated = llr > 0

        # [skip several lines of code]

        update_call_stats(key, num_sites, is_methylated, sequence)
```

It's a little messy to read because the `sites` dictionary is a global outside of `update_call_stats()`.

So overall, it seems like **if you want sites included that are below this threshold, you will have to either:**

1. use an earlier stage of processing (output of `nanopolish call-methylation` I believe according to the docs) or
2. alter the script to change the heuristic thresholds.

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't easy to follow the script. I understood that the whole fragment is discarded if it can be defined which CpG is methylated (if at all). @Wouter de Coster, is that correct?